# HQL update with join condition

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have a relation between entity in hibernate,

Entity **ProgramCardEntity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProgramCardEntity")
public class ProgramCardEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentCardRef", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private VSCardEntity parentCardEntity;

    @Column(name = "Status")
    private String status;

}
```

Entity **VSCardEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VSCardEntity")
public class VSCardEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CardNumber")
    private String cardNumber;
}
```

I want to update the status of *ProgramCardEntity* on given card number of *VSCardEntity*.

I am trying to do this with HQL query:

```
        String query = "update ProgramCardEntity pc inner join pc.parentCardEntity as progCard set pc.status= :status where progCard.cardNumber = :cardNo";

        Query qry = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
        qry.setParameter("status", "Issued");
        qry.setParameter("cardNo", "cardNo");

        int updated = qry.executeUpdate();
```

This gives error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found 'inner' near line 1, column 45 [update ProgramCardEntity pc inner join pc.parentCardEntity as progCard set pc.status= :status where progCard.cardNumber = :cardNo]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
```

Comment: You may not use joins in an update query. In general, you shouldn't use update queries. Get the entity, modify its state. The status should most probably be an enum instead of a String, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use subquery instead of join, something like this:

```
"update ProgramCardEntity pc set pc.status = :status where pc.id in
(select progCard.id from pc.parentCardEntity as progCard where
progCard.cardNumber = :cardNo)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query might work:

```
update ProgramCardEntity  pce set pce.status=: status where pce.parentCardEntity.cardNumber=: cardNumber
```